# Error de conexión a Firebird en C#: Incompatible wire encryption levels requested on client and server

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, firebird

Quisiera saber a qué se debe este error y como poder solucionarlo.

> Incompatible wire encryption levels requested on client and server

Este error ocurre cuando intento abrir la conexión desde C#, estoy usando VS 2015 y FireBird 3.0 y ya tengo instalado el paquete **FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient**.

```
            _cadenaConexion.ServerType = FbServerType.Default;
            _cadenaConexion.Database = _datosConex.rutaBD;
            _cadenaConexion.UserID = _datosConex.usuario;
            _cadenaConexion.Password = _datosConex.contraseña;
            _cadenaConexion.Charset = "NONE";
            _cadenaConexion.Dialect = 3;
            _cadenaConexion.Port = 3050;
            _cadenaConexion.DataSource = "localhost";
            _cadenaConexion.ConnectionLifeTime = 15;
            _cadenaConexion.Pooling = true;
            _cadenaConexion.MinPoolSize = 0;
            _cadenaConexion.MaxPoolSize = 50;
            _cadenaConexion.PacketSize = 8192;

            if (_datosConex == null)
            {  throw new Exception("No existen datos de conexión"); }

            if (_conex != null) { _conex.Close(); }
            _conex = new FbConnection(_cadenaConexion.ConnectionString);
            **_conex.Open();** 
            _transaction = _conex.BeginTransaction("myTrans");
```

Comment: Hola @sergiobadillo. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrías incluir en la pregunta el código que dispara ese error? Quizás te sea útil realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. ¨Para agregar esta información, encontrarás el enlace a **[edit]** debajo de tu pregunta.

Comment: Por favor incluye código donde tienes la excepción, debes ser mas explicito al momento de formular tus preguntas así los usuarios de este foro pueden entender y puedes obtenr respuestas mas rápidas

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que configurar `firebirt.conf`

```
WireCrypt = Enabled
```

Ya han respondido en la versión de ingles [Incompatible wire encryption levels requested on client and server with Firebird ado.net provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37492890/incompatible-wire-encryption-levels-requested-on-client-and-server-with-firebird)

Aca tienes un ejemplo de como hacer la conexión [ConnectionString](https://www.connectionstrings.com/firebird/)

Comment: Gracias amigo, pero ya intente eso, quite el # pero el error persiste.

Comment: @sergiobadillo Tu servidor firebirt esa instalado en que SO? has probado reiniciando el servidor o el servicio para que haga efecto los cambios? Puedes mostrar código donde haces la conexión

Comment: 64 bits, y ya reiniciado el servicio